# How do I make two different ArrayLists reference the same object when Parsing a Json file

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a json data file that has a singular object inside two different ArrayLists:

```
{
  "TA": [
    {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "Jane",
      "lastname": "Doe"
    }
  ],
  "Student": [
    {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "Kevin",
      "lastname": "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

My current parsing method just creates a new Person object for each one and adds them to each List object, but I want my Person object John Smith to only be a singular object referenced by both "TA" list and "Student" list. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Well, you can create your own parser and define an `equals` method to check if then new object getting created already exists.

Comment: The answer would depend on the JSON library you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: Can you add some code of your current parsing? I think @shmosel has the right approach with using a map (can also use a HashSet), but his example is specifically for Jackson which you are apparently not using?

Comment: @magicmn You would have to iterate over the set to find the interned value.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to lower memory usage, you can use a static factory method to intern instances. Assuming you use Jackson:

```
class Person {
    private static Map<Person, Person> cache = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonCreator
    public static Person create(
            @JsonProperty("firstname") String firstname,
            @JsonProperty("lastname") String lastname) {
        Person person = new Person(firstname, lastname);
        return cache.computeIfAbsent(person, Function.identity());
    }

    final String firstname;
    final String lastname;

    private Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Person
                && Objects.equals(((Person)o).firstname, this.firstname)
                && Objects.equals(((Person)o).lastname, this.lastname);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.firstname, this.lastname);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think both arguments of constructor `create` are suppose to add property names as follows: `public static Person create(@JsonProperty("firstname") String firstname, @JsonProperty("lastname") String lastname) {...}`.

Comment: @LHCHIN Thanks, I meant to do that. Though you could avoid it with ParameterNamesModule.

Comment: Since you use HashMap, I think it's better to highlight the hashCode() method instead of equals, since HashMap will use hashCode to differentiate the key of the map.

Comment: @efmalik Fair point. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

TA and Student list are two different list. If you define each list and populate them with the same object (person), yes they would point to the same object. That is object oriented approach.

Parsing a Json and expecting to have the same person object in both arrays is not possible (assuming that person object would get created by the parser). The parser would process each array individually and hence you person object is not going to be the same.

There is a way you can do it that would be by defining person object in a static class. This way you would always get the same instance of the person object.

I your case you will have to create a static person object for each variants (firstname lastname)